# link object files with a linker ascript at different memory adresses for a bootloader

Tags: assembly, linker, bootloader

I'm writing a bootloader just for the fun and to learn more about this topic but I'm facing an issue when compiling my code.

I have 3 files (I've simplified them in order to have less code for you to read):

Boot.s :

```
.code16
.section .boot
.text
.globl _start
.intel_syntax noprefix

_start:
      jmp bpb_end     # Workaround for BIOSes that require a jmp instruction at the beginning..
      nop 

      .org 80 

bpb_end:
       # Clearing the interrupt and direction flag
       cli 
       cld
       jmp 0x0000:_init
...
...
mov dh, 1       # Reading one sector
mov bx, 0x1000

call read_sectors
jmp 0x1000:0x0000

.fill 510-(.-_start), 1, 0        # Filling up space to match 512 bytes as the next MAGIC number must be at the 512th byte.
.word 0xaa55        # This is the MAGIC number for the MBR. It must always be this value !
```

kernel.s :

```
.code16
.section .kernel
.text 
.intel_syntax noprefix

mov si, offset flat:tesing_msg
mov bl, 0xf0
call print16
call new_line16
```

And my linker.ld (which is the problem I guess)

linker.ld :

```
ENTRY(_start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")

SECTIONS {
 . = 0x7c00;

 .boot :
 {

   *(.boot)
 }

 . = 0x1000;
 .kernel : AT(0x7e00)
 {
   *(.kernel)
   *(.text)
   *(.rodata)
   *(.data)
   *(.bss)
   *(COMMON)
 }
 
}
```

What I want to do is the following (correct me if I'm wrong of course):
As the first memory address for a boot-loader has to be "0x7c00" and I load my kernel at memory segment "0x1000", I have to tell my linker to do this. However doesn't really work..

Comment: How does it not work? Also, note that `jmp 0x1000:0x0000` jumps to segment `0x1000` offset `0` which does not match the `. = 0x1000;`

Comment: Furthermore you need to set up `ds` properly. In your effort to _"have less code for us to read"_ you have removed too much, this is not a [mcve] we can test.

Comment: @Jester I'm really sorry, my code was about 100+ lines and I thought it would be more convient for you. My bad. As for the ```jmp``` instruction, I'll try and fix that and report if it has changed.

Comment: @Jester also, Is my linker file the good way to compile my boot loader or is there another way to do it ? By that I mean for exemple removing the .boot section and just have the .kernel section